# Customize VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking for a way to customize a bit the `VBA editor` of Excel. I found this nice `github` post : [VBE Theme Color Editor](https://github.com/gallaux/VBEThemeColorEditor/).

Problem is, I cannot find the `VBE7.DLL` file in my computer.

It should be located at:

- For 64 bit:

  "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL"
- For 32 bit:

  "C:\Program Files( x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL"

Has anyone tried this software (and therefore, can help me out with it) or has an alternative way to customize the VBA editor?

I already tried the `built-in` format editor but colors are kind of ugly...

Thanks for your help! :)

[image]

Comment: If you can't find VBE7.DLL, you could simply search for it - go to a CMD window and enter `DIR C:\VBE*.DLL /S` - hopefully it should list the file you are looking for.  (I found it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1`)

Comment: Yay! Thanks your method worked perfectly. I have absolutely no knowledge about cmd commands but they are efficient. The search method works far way better than the most know (after click on the start button). Any good tuts I should read to get cmd basics ? Thanks again :) (edit : Found it in the same dir as you)

Comment: I have found https://ss64.com/nt/ to be pretty useful

Comment: I found the file here:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7.1\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to close this thread and help other users, @[YowE3K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535336/yowe3k) helped me find the VBE7.DLL file which was located here :

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1
```

If not, try :

1. Open a cmd window (`Windows + R`)
2. Type the following code `DIR C:\VBE*.DLL /S` and press enter

to find the path of your file.
Again thank you to [YowE3K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535336/yowe3k) !

My VBA editor now looks just the way I wanted :

[image]

Comment: At Windows 10 64 bits and Office 64 bits, it is @: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1

Comment: And I confirm that Jean-FIC is pointing the correct folder for a Win 10 64 bits and Office 32 bits: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Windows10 & 64bit OS - Office2021, Office2016, Office365
DLL path is

For 64 bit Excel:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1
For 32 bit Excel:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1

NOT
(For 64 bit:
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL"
For 32 bit:
"C:\Program Files( x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL"
)

I found that after the Office update, my setting was reset, I have to edit again. It was once or two time in a month.
And after applying **DLL**(hexcode) modification,

- you cannot change font of VBE
- you cannot change font size of VBE

So I modified **VBEColorThemeEditor** and named as "O2019" for solving some problem.

I put the MENU to change above in my Help Tool **-VBEColorThemeEditorO2019-**.
This can help you to edit Registry and set your things.

- If you press the Button **"Apply AUTO"**,
  code find what version of Office (64/32bit) you use now and apply proper PATH to edit registry automatically.
- After Office update, Color setting is reset. Then it looks different. press the Button **"Add to Registry"**. It re-apply Registry in your REGEDIT.
- And after applying "ColorTheme" to you DLL, you need to change registry to change font & font family of VBE. input your font and size in the Main Window and press the "Apply each". (If you change in VBE editor - option menu, suddenly close your Setting menu windows. It might be bug?)

I hope that this save your time and enjoy our VBE.

https://github.com/theangkko/VBEThemeColorEditorO2019